# Python | Фильтрация списка

Tags: python, list

Нужно создать функцию, которая берёт список неотрицательных целых чисел и строк и возвращает новый список с отфильтрованными строками | CodeWars

Пример: `filter_list([1,2,'a','b']) == [1,2]`

Я написал следующий код, но он проходит не все тесты (в закрепе 3-ий выдаёт ошибку).

```
def filter_list(l):
    new_l = []
    for i in range (len(l)):
        try:
            int(l[i])
            new_l.append(l[i])
        except ValueError:
            continue
    
    return new_l
```

Тесты:

```
import codewars_test as test
from solution import filter_list

@test.describe('Sample tests')
def sample_tests():
    @test.it('should work for basic examples')
    def basic_examples():
        test.assert_equals(filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b']), [1, 2], 'For input [1, 2, "a", "b"]')
        test.assert_equals(filter_list([1, 'a', 'b', 0, 15]), [1, 0, 15], 'Fot input [1, "a", "b", 0, 15]')
        test.assert_equals(filter_list([1, 2, 'aasf', '1', '123', 123]), [1, 2, 123], 'For input [1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]')
```

Comment: Проверяйте через isinstance

Comment: Можно подробнее, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по третьему тесту строки вида '123' считаются строками и должны пропускаться, а у вас они успешно преобразуются в int и добавляются.

Нужно проверять, что текущий элемент уже имеет тип int, это делается примерно так:

```
if isinstance(l[I], int):
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение через генератор списка(где в список будут добавляться значения, удовлетворявшие условию `isinstance(item, int))`:

```
def filter_list(items):   
    return [item for item in items if isinstance(item, int)]
```

Так же советую вместо range (len(l)) использовать встроенную функцию enumerate, пример:

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    pass
```

Где, i - индекс элемента, item - само значение.

Comment: Да в данном случае индекс так то вообще не нужен, и `enumerate` тоже

Comment: @CrazyElf, а где то видно, что я использую индексы ? Я на будущее посоветовал использовать `enumerate `

Comment: @fghfghfg2 тогда для чего `enumerate` ? если нужно пробежать по списку без индексов достаточно `for el in items`.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, наверное для того, чтобы не использовать range (len(l)) (т.к это не по питоняче)